# ESP32 - Speeding up connection to WiFi AP and REV.3 chip woes

Tags: wireless, esp32, wifi, timing, esp-idf

Esp-IDF 5.0, ESP32 Devkit1 Chip REV.3

Even with the official "station" example stripped to the minimum of code (wifi-related only), connecting to the AP with ESP32 takes 2-3 seconds. That is while sitting right under the router. Sometimes it takes longer, and ESP reports failure+reconnect attempts.

The fastest I could make it go was with the power-saver disabled during the connection using esp_wifi_set_ps(0), which takes just under 2 seconds regardless of the router model:
[image: Wifi start timestamp]

[image: Wifi finish timestamp]

2000ms is an eternity for a chip that can go at 160MHz. Looking up online, I've read that on ESP8266 the connection process takes ~500ms, which is much more like it. Is there any way to bring ESP32 to the same level of speed when it comes to connecting to AP?

Additionally, I've worked with the chip revision 2 prior on an older ESP32 Devkit V1 board. That board additionally had a working automatic uploading of the /bin without having to hold down the BOOT button or add a capacitor to hold down the EN pin. In the photo below you can see that extra cap on the EN button:

[image: Extra cap on the older board]

Again, looking online I've found out that the chip revisions V3 (newer Devkit V1 boards) require longer EN hold times and such require a cap even if there is already one present on the board. Do the V3 chips change anything about how wifi has to be coded though? Most code I have by this point has been written for an older ESP32.

P.S: Code of my Wifi init and start routine is provided:

```
static void fast_scan(void){

        (esp_netif_init());                                             //Init NetIF stack. NetIF stack is a part of ESP-IDF API that acts as a "Network adapter" for the tcp/ip libraries, such as LwIP
        (esp_event_loop_create_default());                              //Create default event loop struct
    
        wifi_init_config_t wifi_init_config = WIFI_INIT_CONFIG_DEFAULT();//Creates wifi config FOR INITIALIZATION ONLY named "wifi_init_config"
        (esp_wifi_init(&wifi_init_config));                              //Initialize wifi hardware with the the default config
    
        (esp_event_handler_instance_register(WIFI_EVENT, ESP_EVENT_ANY_ID, &wifi_event_handler, NULL, NULL)); //Register all WIFI events with the event handler.
        (esp_event_handler_instance_register(IP_EVENT, IP_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP, &wifi_event_handler, NULL, NULL));//Register IP event "IP_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP" with the event handler
    
        // Initialize default station as network interface instance (esp-netif)
        esp_netif_create_default_wifi_sta();
    
    
        // Initialize and start WiFi
        wifi_config_t wifi_config = {
            .sta = {
                .ssid = "MyAP_2023",              
                .password = "superSecrit", 
                .scan_method = WIFI_FAST_SCAN,
                .sort_method = WIFI_CONNECT_AP_BY_SIGNAL,
                .threshold.rssi = -127,
                .threshold.authmode = 0,
                //.bssid_set = 0,
            },
        };
        (esp_wifi_set_mode(WIFI_MODE_STA));
        (esp_wifi_set_config(WIFI_IF_STA, &wifi_config)); //WIFI_IF_STA is number 0 (integer)
        (esp_wifi_start());//Start the wifi hardware
        esp_wifi_set_ps(0); //Power saver off (speeds-up the connection)
        
        ESP_LOGI(WIFI_STATUS, "Wifi 1 done"); //Prints the message in the main console with a timestamp (millis).
        //printf("Wifi 1 done.\n\r");
        vTaskDelay(5000/portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
        esp_wifi_set_ps(WIFI_PS_MIN_MODEM); //Re-enable power-saving on the Wifi modem
        ESP_LOGI(WIFI_STATUS, "Wifi 2 done"); //Prints the message in the main console with a timestamp (millis).
    }
```